# RecyclerView duplicates the adapterPostion when I use findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(postion)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

I am trying to set progress bar on RecyclerView based on the AdapterPostion by using findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(postion). but it get duplicted while scrolling the recyclerview can anyone please tell me how can I fix this.

I am getting view by postion by the following code

```
private RecyclerView.ViewHolder findViewForAsset(String id){
    int i = 0;
    for(Entity image: imagesList){
        i++;
        if(asset.getId().equals(id)){
            break;
        }
    }

    return mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
}
```

I am updating the progress by :

```
public void updateProgressView(String id,boolean isDownloading){
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder assetView = findViewForAsset(id);
    if (assetView == null) {
        return;
    }
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) assetView.itemView.findViewById(R.id.asset_download_progress);
    final ImageView downloadMask = (ImageView) assetView.itemView.findViewById(R.id.download_mask);
    final ImageView assetimage = (ImageView) assetView.itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_asset_image);

    if(isDownloading){
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        downloadMask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        runOnUiThread(  new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downloadMask.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of Entity image: image? it is not used in your for loop

Comment: sorry there was a spelling mistake while I change the name for posting in this question but the problem is not there if I try to download one image the progress bar is showing in the corresponding view but also in some other view while I am scrollong when download in progress